# Getting Subscript out of range error when copying text from Sheet1 to Sheet9

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to copy something from Sheet1 to Sheet 9 but keep getting subscript out of range error. Created a dummy excel just to test out the code and it works there but doesn't work in my main one. Please help.

```
Sub Copy()
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet9").Range("K1")
End Sub
```

[Error message and VBA window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZCLL.jpg)

Comment: Try `worksheets()`?

Comment: Most likely is that there is not a worksheet called `Sheet1` or `Sheet9`.  When using `Sheets()` or `Worksheets()` you are looking at the editable sheet name show on the tab and not the code name.

Comment: `Sheet1` is "Synthesis" in your workbook, same situation probably for `Sheet9`

Comment: Try using the worksheets' code names: `Sheet1.Range("B5").Copy Destination:=Sheet9.Range("K1")`.